# VS Code - C# Extension - Extending further

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, omnisharp

*** UPDATE ***

Below my original question but I've learned more about VS Code Extensions.

Looking through the OmniSharp C# Extension seems like ideally I could add some canned code before and after the text in the VS Code editor before validation takes place. I've looked for hooks where this could be done, for example, before _validateOpenDocuments() in diagnosticsProvider.ts. The diagnostics items would have to be modified to have the right position in the editor code, subtracting out the canned code inserted.

Not sure if anyone familiar with how OmniSharp works could give me some pointers on the idea above.

Thanks,
Enrique

I have an application (working fine, written in C#) that uses C# code as its scripting language to generate drawings. It has its own code editor but I'd like to use the excellent VS Code as front-end.

The following is a very simple valid script:

```
NoLoop = true;

MP.SetBackgroundColor(72, 60, 0);
MP.SetPen(1, 3, 255, 255, 255, 64);

List<MathPoint> grid = MP.Sheet(200, 100, 200, 0.0, 0.0);

result = MP.Center(MP.Transform(grid, xS:+1.0, yS:-1.0, zR:+0.0), 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0);
```

The OmniSharp C# extension works great and I would like to extend it so it better fits my need.

1) When you write a script in my app you don't have to write the C# namespace, class and method wrappers, it is added automatically. The C# extension complains "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected .." on the first line.

2) My wrapper also predefines some members such as "bool NoLoop = false;" and "List< MathPoint > result = new List< MathPoint >();" in the example. The C# extension obviously doesn't know this and does not recognize these members. Would like add IntelliSense support for these.

3) My wrapper includes other namespaces that make other classes and methods available such as "MP.Sheet(...)" and "MP.Center(...)" in the example. Would also like add IntelliSense support.

My question: Is there a way to install the OmniSharp C# extension and then add to it with the above features or do I have to modify the OmniSharp C# extension code and create my own fork?

If I can just add functionality, any hints on each of the 3 changes above?

Thanks in advance for any help on this, I'm new to VS Code Extensions.

[image: Sample script in VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3746

Thanks